# How do i remove default SharePoint Search box on intranet Site?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have edited my default.master page and v4.master  by setting the Visibility:hidden using SharePoint Designer, in the designer i can see that the search box is hidden but when running my intranet site Search box is still visible. I also tried removing the delegation control but that doesnt help, the account i am using  has full control and is an administrator account? Any idea what i should do next please?

Comment: Have you published and approved the master page? Make sure you are editing the correct master page that is set (Check site settings -> master page to make sure)

Comment: Okay my site master page is v4.master which i edited and my system master page is v4.@@@.master which is not the default.master i edited, and yes i did approve and publish the master pages i edited. should i change the system master page too?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this

**Option #1 using a hidden panel**

Move the Content Placeholder as below

```
<!--- --- ---  Hidden Placeholders --- --- --->
<asp:Panel visible="false" runat="server">
<!-- Place unused Content Placeholders here -->
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" Visible="true" runat="server">
       <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"/>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Panel>
<!--- --- ---  End of Hidden Placeholders --- --- --->
```

**Option #2 using CSS**

Use SharePoint Designer to edit your master page and put the below style tag just after the SharePoint style controls

```
<SharePoint:CssLink runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:Theme runat="server"/>
<style>
 #SRSB {display:none}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reapply the masterpage to the page after making changes to the masterpage. BTW you should not modify the out of box masterpages but create the new one base on existing one.

Comment: Okay i am not sure i follow you, I have created backups of both the master pages i have edited, and published the ones i edited(recent changes), i only want to disable/hide/remove the search box on the top upper right, i was against making changes on the 14 HIVE Search.xml,please explain further what you meant!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS:

```
#searchInputBox { display: none; }
```

OR

```
#SearchBox { display: none; }
```